# Strange (atleast for me) behavior in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

The following code snippet in a Django template (v 1.1) doesn't work.

```
{{ item.vendors.all.0 }} ==> returns "Test"
```

but the following code snippet, doesn't hide the paragraph!

```
{% ifnotequal item.vendors.all.0 "Test" %}
<p class="view_vendor">Vendor(s): {{item.vendors.all.0}} </p><br />
{% endifnotequal %}
```

Any tips on what's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`item.vendors.all.0` doesn't return `"Test"`: It returns a vendor object, which gives `"Test"` when converted to a string. If you just compare the object with `"Test"`, it will never be equal.

Try converting the object to a string before comparing:

```
{% ifnotequal item.vendors.all.0|stringformat:"s" "Test" %}
```

Comment: Or `ifnotequal item.vendors.all.0.name "Test"`, where `name` is the relevant model field.

Comment: I realized it's returning "vendor" object, i.e. the __unicode__ method is called when I print but not when I compare them. But when I print "name", the model field its empty...But the solution works fine. Thanks.